# AWS Cognito js: init and authenticate CognitoUser using existing Refresh/Access/id Tokens and username

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

in our use-case we need to authenticate a user using

```
AuthFlow: REFRESH_TOKEN
```

essentially use [this method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property)

is there a way to do it using amazon-cognito-identity-js package?
we have the idToken, accessToken and refreshToken stored in localstorage, we could also store the user's username (sub)

our first idea was to use "userSession.refreshSession" but the problem is that for us to use this method we need to call UserPool.getCurrentUser() and in our case it returns "null" because the tokens were obtained without using sdk and we don't have CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.****.LastAuthUser and other keys the lib relies on in our local storage yet.

is there a way to init CognitoUser object and call auth against it using the user's tokens and email/username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UserPool.getCurrentUser()` returns `null` if the login becomes without `amazon-cognito-identity-js` and a username doesn't store in the localStorage with key `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.${this.clientId}.LastAuthUser` (see [getCurrentUser](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/CognitoUserPool.js#L146C2-L161))

If you are going to manage tokens manually you need to do:

```js
const poolData = {
 UserPoolId: '...', // Your user pool id here
 ClientId: '...', // Your client id here
};
const username = '' // TODO: get user name from a storage
const refreshToken = '' // TODO: get token from a storage

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
const userData = {
 Username: username,
 Pool: userPool,
};
const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.refreshSession(
  new CognitoRefreshToken({ 
    RefreshToken: refreshToken 
  }), 
  (error, session) => {
    /* TODO: save new tokens to your local storage */
  })
```

where the session is an instance of [CognitoUserSession](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/src/CognitoUserSession.js)

Note: I would recommend you use your backend to refresh the token if you are using it for sign-in/sign-up

Comment: thanks @pavlo-naumenko there was "error" arg missed in the callback in your code sample, once that was corrected it worked like a charm!

Comment: Right, it's error-first callback. The fix applied